# AppleScript - Get complete information of current iTunes track

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes

I'm trying to return the information of the current iTunes Track, which is playing on my computer.

I can get single informations like this:

```
tell application "iTunes"
get name of current track
end tell
```

This returns `Thunderstruck` for example.

But is it possible that I can get more information of the current track so it returns something like this:

```
"AC/DC, Thunderstruck, Iron Man 2"
```

Is this possible? Or do I have to create multiple scripts?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get `name`, `artist` and `album`

```
tell application "iTunes"
    get {name, artist, album} of current track
end tell
```

The result is a list

---

To get everything

```
tell application "iTunes"
    get properties of current track
end tell
```

The result is a record

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using JXA, then:

- To get track properties as a JavaScript object:

```js
// File: GetTrackInfo.jxa
const appMusic = Application("com.apple.Music");
const currentTrack = appMusic.currentTrack();
const properties = currentTrack.properties()
// Get track info as a JSON
console.log(JSON.stringify(properties, null, 2))
// Get certain track info property.
console.log(properties.name)
```

- To get single track property:

```js
// File: GetTrackInfoAndCopyToClipboard.jxa
const currentApp = Application.currentApplication();
currentApp.includeStandardAdditions = true;

const appMusic = Application("com.apple.Music");
const currentTrack = appMusic.currentTrack();
const result = `${currentTrack.artist()} - ${currentTrack.name()} @ ${currentTrack.album()}`;
console.log(`Result: ${result}`);

// Bonus, copying track into into Clipboard and sending notification.
currentApp.setTheClipboardTo(result);
currentApp.displayNotification(result);
```